# Operator is not overloaded: "Constant String" + "untyped"

Tags: delphi, comparison, operator-overloading, pascal, procedure

I'm reading from a dataset into an SQL function which is then written to a file, I created a little procedure which checks for empty fields and then replaces them with null, fields which are non-empty have quotes placed around them.

However when I goto compile I get the error

```
Error: Operator is not overloaded: "Constant String" + "untyped"
```

Frankly I have no idea what this means, I checked the fpc parser messages help, which says

```
You’re trying to use an overloaded operator when it is not overloaded for this type.
```

Which I found even more confusing. Can someone help me out here? I think it's because I'm doing a comparison in my procedure but could be wrong.

```
procedure isNull(str : AnsiString);
  begin
    if str = EmptyStr then
      str := Null
    else
      str := '' + str + '';
  end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i : Integer;
  addLine, f : string;
  list : TStringList;
begin
  f := 'info.sql';
  list := TStringList.Create;

  with AddressData do begin
    for i := 0 to RecordCount do begin

    RecNo := i;
    addLine := 'CALL CONT__Add(' + isNull(Fields[0].AsString) +')'; // Much more of this but fails at first call of procedure
    list.Add(addLine);
    end;
  list.SaveToFile(f);
  list.free;
   end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
addLine := 'CALL CONT__Add(' + isNull(Fields[0].AsString) +')';
```

This fails because `isNull` is a procedure and so does not evaluate to anything. In order for this code to compile `isNull` would need to be a function whose return type could be coerced to a string.

I'm finding it difficult to know how you should change your program because it's not obvious what it is trying to do. Not least because a function named `isNull` should test its input against null and return a boolean value.

I also confess bafflement at

```
str := '' + str + '';
```

That does nothing at all, makes no modification to the value of `str`.

My best guess is that you want something like this:

```
function PrepareField(const str: string): string;
begin
  if str = '' then
    Result := Null
  else
    Result := '''' + str + '''';
end;
```

This code makes me worry about SQL injection. Have you accounted for that risk?

Comment: Ack, schoolboy error, I thought procedures could return as well. Thanks for the assist.

Comment: `Null()` returns a `Variant`, which is then being converted to a `String`.  When `str` is empty, you should be returning an empty string `''` instead of calling `Null()`.

Comment: @Remy Unless `Null` is locally defined to be something else

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: That is not evident in the posted question. And since it is using the RTL's `EmptyStr` const, presumably it is also using the RTL's copy of `Null`.

Comment: @Remy This is FPC rather than Delphi. If Null really were Variants.Null it wouldn't be much use in an SQL query. You cannot be 100% sure what Null is.

Answer (score 0):

Defining isNull as follows compiles. Thanks for the pointer David.

```
function isNull(str : AnsiString) : String;
begin
  if str = EmptyStr then
    str := Null
  else
    str := '' + str + '';
  isNull := str;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several errors in you code

```
procedure isNull(str : AnsiString); // str assignments inside procedure does not takes effect outside procedure, use var str
  begin
    if str = EmptyStr then
      str := Null // Incompatible types AnsiString (str) and Variant (Null). May be you means 'Null' (in quotes)?
    else
      str := '' + str + ''; // concatenation with empty strings, use QuotedStr(str)
  end;
```

And as @DavidHeffernan said `isNull` is a procedure and can not be used in function manner.